# Multipeer connection Webrtc Flutter

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I am trying to make 3 peer video chat using Webrtc in Flutter. A needs to see B and C. B needs to see A and C. C needs to A and B. I also use socket.io for signalling server. I used 2 peerconnection. two peer connection is successful. When I tried to connect the third one and tried to pass offer I got an error.

**to execute 'createAnswer' on 'RTCPeerConnection': PeerConnection cannot create an answer in a state other than have-remote-offer or have-local-pranswer.**

is my approach is bad for multiple peer connection?

Answer (score 1):

A mesh of 3 users means each user sets up two connections, one to each of the other two users. At each client's end, these are two entirely different RTCPeerConnections, and you can't reuse candidates between them, as each candidate contains port numbers allocated specifically for the media and the target it is to be sent to.

If you know how to set up one connection, you know how to set up two. Just keep things separate.

Comment: yeah. In code, I tried to do that. first create one peer connection then  another one.

Comment: Do I need to create room for this to work?

Answer (score -1):

just set 1 connection and try to use the direction: many to many

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).